# Python finding the average of a list with averages of sublists

Tags: python

In this program I am trying to find the average of the entire list, finding the average of sublists first. For example, this should find the average of 32 and 12 (equal to 22), then the average of 22 and 45 (equal to 33.5), and finally the average of 33.5, 18, and 60. This is what I have so far. I am getting an Index error.

```
testlist = [[18], [45, [32, 12]], [60]]

for e in testlist:
  avg = sum([e[1] for e in testlist])/len(testlist)

print(avg)
```

Comment: Not all `e`s in `testlist` have a second element; indexing in Python (and many other languages) is zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses 0-based indexing just like many other popular languages so `testlist[1]` gives you the second element instead of first one.

Apart from the error you are getting, I think your question is a perfect example for recursion because this will give you the ability of handling 2 or 3 level deep sublists without any issue:

```
>>> def avg(lst):
...     total = 0
...     for i in lst:
...         if isinstance(i, list):
...             total = total + avg(i)
...         else:
...             total = total + i
...     return float(total) / len(lst)

>>> testlist = [[18], [45, [32, 12]], [60]]
>>> avg(testlist)
37.166666666666664
```

Answer (score 0):

I think recursion can be used to solve your problem

```
testlist = [[18], [45, [32, 12]], [60]]

def average(the_list):
    if len(the_list) == 0:
        return 0
    accumulation = 0
    for element in the_list:
        if type(element) == list:
            element = average(element)
        accumulation = accumulation + element
    return accumulation / len(the_list)

print(average(testlist)) // 37.166666666666664
```